# Custom Directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, snap.js

Hello I have the following directive for a hamburger menu:

```
angular.module('app.directives')
    .directive('hamburger', hamburger);

    // Injecting Dependencies
    hamburger.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout'];

    // Directive's Function, Where All Code is Declared and Executed
    function hamburger($rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                open: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'tpls/directives/hamburger.html',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

                scope.$watch('open', function(newValue, oldValue) {

                    if (newValue == true) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            elem.addClass("open");
                        }, 2000);

                        console.log("This is true");
                    }
                    else {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            elem.removeClass("open");
                        }, 2000);

                        console.log("This is false");
                    }

                });


            }
        }
    }
```

This is the template:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

This is how I use it in my view:

```
<hamburger class="menu-btn2 pull-left" snap-toggle="left" open="vm.toggleMenu" ng-click="toggle()" ng-dblclick="doNothing()"></hamburger>
```

Now I have a function in my view that adds a class to an element on click.  This opens a side menu.

Now when my side menu is open I want to change the icon of my menu by adding an "open" class.

On my directive I have an attribute named "open" which I bind to both my controller and my directive.  Inside my directive's **link** function I have a watch that is supposed to watch the value of the variable bound to "open" when it changes to true it should an a class "open" to the element when it changes to "false" it should remove the class "open" from the element.

I have tried everything so far but cannot seem to get this to work.  There are no errors shown in my terminal, I tried to do a `console.log()` in my $watch to see if it was actually detecting when the value changed but that didn't work either, nothing was logged in my console.

This is my toggle function:

```
vm.toggleMenu = false;
vm.toggle = function () {
  vm.toggleMenu = !vm.toggleMenu;
};
```

Comment: It's likely that you're using the wrong binding type, `@` bindings are for strings. You may want to do a two way binding with `=`. Read more: https://blog.umur.io/2013/07/02/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: Yes I know this already.  I actually used "=" initially when it didn't work I changed it to "@".

Comment: This code looks fine, do you have the code for your controller that is attached to the view for `<hamburger class="menu-btn2 pull-left" snap-toggle="left" open="vm.toggleMenu" ng-click="toggle()" ng-dblclick="doNothing()"></hamburger>`?

Comment: Yes please, I will add that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found what the problem was, I was using the controllerAs syntax thereby creating an instance of my controller (how I believe it works) as **vm**.  For some reason I still do not fully understand I am unable to bind that attribute to a variable within that instance.  It worked when I changed it to **scope.toggleMenu** instead of **vm.toggleMenu**.

I'm quite new to angularjs so I'm going to assume that two way binding only works with scope variables or when you're not using the ControllerAs syntax.